# Clear entire row data except the first row using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using below code to clear contents from A2:H2 rows except the first one where I have the header. This code works well if there are no blank cells in between. But how can I clear everything eventhough there is a blank cell?

```
Sub Clear()

Dim s1Sheet As Worksheet

Set s1Sheet = Workbooks("StockScreen.xlsm").Sheets("TimeStampWork")

s1Sheet.Range(s1Sheet.Range("A2:H2"), s1Sheet.Range("A2:H2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Below is my sample code:

```
Sub ClearContentExceptFirst()
    Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: just wanted to mention that there are also other "clear" methods:
.Clear | .ClearComments | .ClearContents | .ClearFormats | .ClearHyperlinks | .ClearNotes | .ClearOutline

Answer (score 6):

If you simply want to delete the entire row from a specific row number to a specific row number, you can avoid using the `Range` and `Cell` properties, but instead you can use the `Rows` property:

```
s1Sheett.Rows("2:10").ClearContents
```

Or if you want to delete the everything from a specific row number to the last row with data, you can use:

```
s1Sheett.Rows("2:" & currentSheet.Rows.Count).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what works for me

```
Sheets("MY_SHEET_NAME").Rows("2:" & Sheets("MY_SHEET_NAME").Rows.Count).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

I use below code which checks whether there is any row to delete.

```
If Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    
    ActiveSheet.Rows("2:" & Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
s1Sheet.Range(s1Sheet.Range("A2:H2"), s1Sheet.Range("A2:H2").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
```

try

```
s1Sheet.Range("A2:H" & s1Sheet.Cells(s1Sheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).
```

or

```
With s1Sheett
    .Range("A2:H" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
End With
```

here last row with data is counted using `Column A`.